# SSRS Report: Set a Display Message When a Certain Dataset Returns NULL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SQL report with two different parameters. The first parameter is hidden, and gets the default value from somewhere else. The second parameter gets default value from the first parameter, and it might return NULL values.

My question is, is it possible to automatically display a message on the report when the second parameter returns NULL values?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a message dialog (pop-up message) then you cannot do this using the SSRS web portal by default.

If you just want to display some text on the report then you can easily do this.

Add a text box, set the value to whatever text you like, or to an expression if it needs to be more dynamic.

Then set the hidden property of the text box to something like

```
=IIF(Parameters!myParam.Value = nothing, False, True)
```

If the parmeter you want to check is multi-value then just reference index 0 to pick up the first entry like this.

```
=IIF(Parameters!myParam.Value(0) = nothing, False, True)
```